# Reference Monday.com item ID in Github commit message

Tags: github, monday.com

When I reference an Item ID from the Monday App in my git commit it should show up because I have following integration enabled: `When a pulse ID is mentioned in a commit in this repository, create an update to the relevant pulse.`

I can't get it to show in the item's updates. I tried it like `#abc123` or just `abc123`, both don't do anything and the documentation doesn't seem to be offering an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am a developer on monday.com and i'll be glad to help you!

When stating the things you tried, yes the way to go to mention a pulse is 
`#{PULSE_ID}` but I do wonder, where do you get your pulse id from?

For example, it is shown at the end of the URL:
[image: relevant pulse id]

Please note that the commit has to be pushed first to your branch/master for it to show up on monday, if it's only locally it won't send us webhooks about it.

Comment: We used one of the predefined columns named 'Item ID'. Do we have to include the braces #{123} or only the # symbol?

Comment: Just #number, no need for the curly braces

Comment: Is there a way to change the status of an item to complete from a commit?

Comment: I tried like you said, but for a subitem, and for subitem, when pushing commits to github, it's not working.